# How to get/set Bluetooth MTU value in Linux with command line tool (hciconfig/bluetoothctl)

Tags: linux, bluetooth-gatt, pybluez

I'm developing an embedded Linux device as a BLE peripheral to communicate to Android App.

I start from the github project [python-gatt-server](https://github.com/Jumperr-labs/python-gatt-server).

Now there's some throughput bottleneck and I doubt it's about MTU setting.

The output of `hciconfig` is as follows:

```sh
root@linux:~# hciconfig
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
        BD Address: C0:EE:40:3B:31:A0  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
        UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
        RX bytes:1392 acl:0 sco:0 events:78 errors:0
        TX bytes:1752 acl:0 sco:0 commands:78 errors:0
```

1. There're 2 MTU settings: `ACL MTU: 1021:8` and `SCO MTU: 64:1`, what are they meaning respectively?
2. I heard different chipset support different MTU settings. How to find those values?
3. How to set MTU with command line tools like `hciconfig` or `bluetoothctl`?

Answer (score 1):

You can change MTU value by using gatttool. You need to use gatttool -I command. Then connect you device. You can use help command.
MTU 1234 will works

Answer (score 1):

**--- answer for GATT only ---**

---

the two option from `hciconfig` cmd not for gatt mtu.
//meaning not very sure,  practice does not work

### 一. api or cli

gatt mtu can be set in (by programing api, or cli)

- server: btgatt-server,
- client: btgatt-client, gatttool
  //they all work as a demo instance, only set current instance, not global settings.

//cli

#### btgatt-server, btgatt-client

```bash
//only set in cmdline args
tools/btgatt-server --mtu 123 ..
tools/btgatt-client --mtu 123
```

//btgatt-server can seen mtu change, passively

```
[GATT server]# att: > 02 7b 00                                         
[GATT server]# att: ATT PDU received: 0x02
server: MTU exchange complete, with MTU: 123
[GATT server]# att: ATT op 0x03
[GATT server]# att: < 03 05 02
```

#### gatttool

//gatttool (only set with result, no interface do query only)

```
//in cmdline arg
tools/gatttool --mtu 123 ..

//in runtime 
tools/gatttool --interactive
[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX][LE]> mtu 123
MTU was exchanged successfully: 123
[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX][LE]> mtu 122
Command Failed: MTU exchange can only occur once per connection.
//in other app, it can be set many times.

//mtu   <value>     Exchange MTU for GATT/ATT
```

they all not provided query only interface yet (bluez-5.53),
you can change code implement one.

#### c api

//api

```c
int mtu = 123;
server->gatt = bt_gatt_server_new(server->db, server->att, mtu, 0);

mtu = bt_att_get_mtu(server->att);
printf("--- get mtu: %d\n", mtu);  // got 672 // wrong from L2CAP (on my test device
    
bt_att_set_mtu(server->att, 23);  // conservative size
```

### 二. communication

or by communication

- gatt negotiation by `exchange mtu`
  // client send mtu req(with client mtu), server replay (with server mtu): then they use MIN of them.
  // by default it's 23
  // some ble test app, can change mtu in need at runtime.
- from link layer, L2CAP negotiate mtu.

NOTE:
in bluez, mtu from link layer (L2CAP) may overide mtu from gatt api.
and for BR/EDR link device, exchange mtu is disabled.

so, if L2CAP got wrong mtu, the communication may be abnormal.

---

### 三. Typical value

- 23  //min, default
- 517 //max from bluz
- 527 //max from some android device

if mtu is 23, gatt may split big packet into many small packets to transmit.
// should still work.